# Could not load 'vjslib' still after installing J# Re-Dist 2.0

Tags: redistributable, j#, nfop

I am developing an app with vb.net to create pdf with xsl using [NFOP](http://nfop.sourceforge.net/).

Getting below exception on line `spdf = eng.Run(objFOStream.ToString())`.

I work on windows 7 32 bit with VS 2010

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'vjslib, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified." & vbCrLf & "File name:
>   'vjslib, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'" & vbCrLf & "   at
>   ApacheFop.Engine.Run(String foDocument)" & vbCrLf & "   at
>   WindowsApplication1.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\Projects\IP\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line
>   18" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "=== Pre-bind state information ===" &
>   vbCrLf & "LOG: User = sysabdu\abdu" & vbCrLf & "LOG: DisplayName =
>   vjslib, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" & vbLf & " (Fully-specified)" &
>   vbCrLf & "LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///D:/Projects/IP/WindowsApplication1/WindowsApplication1/bin/Debug/"
>   & vbCrLf & "LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL" & vbCrLf & "Calling
>   assembly : ApacheFop.Net, Version=1.0.963.3928, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null." & vbCrLf & "===" & vbCrLf & "LOG: This bind
>   starts in default load context." & vbCrLf & "LOG: No application
>   configuration file found." & vbCrLf & "LOG: Using host configuration
>   file: " & vbCrLf & "LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config."
>   & vbCrLf & "LOG: Post-policy reference: vjslib, Version=1.0.3300.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" & vbCrLf & "LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/Projects/IP/WindowsApplication1/WindowsApplication1/bin/Debug/vjslib.DLL."
>   & vbCrLf & "LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/Projects/IP/WindowsApplication1/WindowsApplication1/bin/Debug/vjslib/vjslib.DLL."
>   & vbCrLf & "LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/Projects/IP/WindowsApplication1/WindowsApplication1/bin/Debug/vjslib.EXE."
>   & vbCrLf & "LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/Projects/IP/WindowsApplication1/WindowsApplication1/bin/Debug/vjslib/vjslib.EXE."
>   & vbCrLf & "

Answer (score 1):

You need require install **Visual J#**

Microsoft Visual J# Version 2.0 Redistributable Package
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4712

Notes:

> With vjslib 2.0 you may also need to set your application pool to
>   allow 32bit applications.

**Single-File Assemblies**

> The simplest applications that use no any additional assemblies other
>   than the standard runtime (mscorlib.dll and, for J# applications,
>   vjslib.dll and vjscor.dll) are compiled in an EXE file without use of
>   the references option. These are referred to as self-contained or
>   single-file assemblies.

Comment: For me is working: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4712 - Select language: English